# How to change ANSI_NULLS option for a table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table that mistakenly has ANSI_NULLS option set to OFF. I'd like to set it ON for this table. The table has millions rows of data. Is it possible to change this option without creating a new table with ANSI_NULLS ON, moving all the data into this new table and renaming this table. Currently downtime for using this solution makes it impractical. Is there another way?

Comment: This is possible as a metadata only change. See [Changing ANSI_NULLS setting on a table](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16229/changing-ansi-nulls-setting-on-a-table)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as my quick and dirty tests show (using ALTER TABLE and ALTER INDEX), no

The setting is captured at CREATE time.

Comment: Isn't ANSI_NULLS a connection-specific setting?  In other words, even with a table that is created with `ANSI_NULLS OFF`, if the connection has `ANSI_NULLS ON` it will regard `SELECT` statements with `ANSI_NULLS ON`

Comment: @Shark: ANSI_NULLs is connection specific, but the setting at CREATE time is stored. This matters for computed columns, indexed views etc