# Changing ANSI_NULLS setting on a table

Tags: sql-server-2008

Can we use the following query to update ANSI_NULLS option.

```
sp_configure 'allow updates', 1

reconfigure with override

update sysobjects set status = status | 0x20000000 where name = 'tblClient'
```

I am not sure what it is doing. I got this after searching for a solution. Our db is SQL server 2008.

But while i am running this i got an error like this `"Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed."`

Please give your suggestions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Updating system tables directly is unsupported and unsafe. The structure of them has changed since 2000 so the code you have won't work against them anyway.

It is sometimes possible to use `ALTER TABLE ... SWITCH` to do this as a metadata only change however.

A full worked example below.

```
/*Create table with option off*/ 
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF; 

CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (X INT) 

/*Add some data*/ 
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable VALUES (1),(2),(3) 

/*Confirm the bit is set to 0*/ 
SELECT uses_ansi_nulls, * 
FROM   sys.tables 
WHERE  object_id = object_id('dbo.YourTable') 

GO 

BEGIN TRY 
    BEGIN TRANSACTION; 
    /*Create new table with identical structure but option on*/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON; 
    CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTableNew (X INT) 

    /*Metadata only switch*/
    ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable  SWITCH TO dbo.YourTableNew;

    DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable; 

    EXECUTE sp_rename N'dbo.YourTableNew', N'YourTable','OBJECT'; 

    /*Confirm the bit is set to 1*/ 
    SELECT uses_ansi_nulls, * 
    FROM   sys.tables 
    WHERE  object_id = object_id('dbo.YourTable') 

    /*Data still there!*/ 
    SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.YourTable

    COMMIT TRANSACTION; 
END TRY 

BEGIN CATCH 
    IF XACT_STATE() <> 0 
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION; 

    PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE(); 
END CATCH;
```

One caveat however is that this does not always work. Adding a check constraint with definition `CHECK (X <> NULL)` causes it to fail with

> ALTER TABLE SWITCH statement failed. Table 'YourTableNew' has a column
>   level check constraint 'CK_*YourTableNew*_X__37A5467C' on column 'X'
>   that is not loadable for semantic validation.

This makes sense as the semantics of the constraint do change with the setting.

If you encounter this you could consider temporarily removing the problematic constraints etc and adding them back after the switch or just biting the bullet and recreating the table in a more conventional way.

Comment: Thank you.. But then what about the data in your table?

Comment: @mahesh - That's still there. Try running `SELECT * FROM dbo.YourTable` at the end of the demo code. The data pages are unchanged. Just the table definition is updated.

Comment: we have got around 100 tables, So we have to do this thing for all the tables. Is there any option to do it more simply like in any one step configuration or any method to automate this thing..:)

Comment: @mahesh - You probably could automate it using SMO to script the `CREATE` table statement or TSQL [similar to here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21551/73226). Make sure you have good error handling!

Comment: I am creating the new table by using the script table as option in SSMS for the particular table. In that case the name of constraints like primary key and foreign key needs to be changed manually. Is any other opton to get rid off this manual editing..

Comment: Similarly there are some foreign key constraints on other table with the primary key on this table. So there is showing an error like we can't do 'ALTER SWITCH TO'. So in this case i think we have to manually drop those constraints and after creating the new table, create these constraints. Is there any other way to do these things.

Comment: @mahesh - Not something I've had to automate before, sorry. If I was going to do it and doing it manually was too time consuming I'd look at using the SMO Scripter functionality.